# How to embed fonts in EPS images with PDFLatex of WinEDT

Tags: eps, winedt, epstopdf, embedding

I am using WinEdt version 9.0. I am using following packages among others:

```
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

However, when I run TeX -> PDF -> PDFLaTex the resulting PDF does not embed fonts in .eps figures. I found that ps2pdf will embed the fonts and set the recommended switches in Options -> ExecutionModes -> ps2pdf, but TeX -> PDF -> ps2pdf is grayed out and I cannot use it.

Comment: Unrelated to the quesrtion , but `epsfig` should be used at it is totally obsolete (it  is a latex 2.09 package). Did you try converting your .eps file to .pdf format.? `Epspdf-setup` is a gui application, written in texlua, that does a fine job.

Comment: Thank you. I think I copied the usepackage directives from another file, that's how the package epsfig got included. It definitely seems like I have to look at another application to accomplish this, so, I will download the epspdf-setup as you suggest.

Comment: Since I used overleaf.com before, I first tried to port my paper there, and everything is embedded now.